# Defining $\mathbb{Z}_n$ as a subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ or as a set of equivalence classes

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic, definition

In Gallian's *Contemporary Abstract Algebra*, he defines $\mathbb{Z}_n$ as the set (see 10e, Ch.2: p. 39 - 40)$$\mathbb{Z}_n := \{0, 1, 2, 3, \dots, n-1 \}.$$

To be clear, at this point in the text, equivalence classes modulo $n$ have been introduced, and Gallian takes care to denote them by $[a]$. The reader would have no reason to believe that the 0, 1, 2, 3, etc. in the set above are anything but elements of the integers (I've searched the book for comments concerning this issue).

In Hungerford's *Introduction to Abstract Algebra*, $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is defined using equivalence classes modulo $n$: $$\mathbb{Z}_n := \{ [0], [1], [2], \dots, [n-1] \} \not \subset \mathbb{Z} \quad \text{where} \quad [a] = \{ b \in \mathbb{Z} \, \vert \, b = a \bmod n\}.$$

In both texts, the authors go on to say that $\mathbb{Z}_n$ forms a group under addition modulo n, though I suppose in the first, the "addition" has mod $n$ built in, while in the second, this gets buried in the definition of addition for equivalence classes mod $n$; that is

- For the first: $+: \mathbb{Z}_n \times \mathbb{Z}_n \to \mathbb{Z}_n$ is defined by $a+b = (a+b) \bmod n$
- For the second: $+: \mathbb{Z}_n \times \mathbb{Z}_n \to \mathbb{Z}_n$ is defined by $[a] + [b] = [a +_\mathbb{Z} b]$

**Question**: Is it important to distinguish between these definitions, or is it just a matter of perspective? What benefits are there in defining $\mathbb{Z}_n$ using equivalence classes rather than as just as a subset of the integers (pedagogically or otherwise)?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133378/discussion-on-question-by-mobius-defining-mathbbz-n-as-a-subset-of-mathbb).

Comment: Please cite the Gallian edition and section / page number.

Comment: The former is simply a normal-form representation of the latter - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/646600/242). The equivalence class approach is more general since in an arbitrary group or ring there may be no convenient (or computable) choice of normal form from each equivalence class (this comment was originally posted before any answer, but alas it was migrated to chat).

Comment: See also the remarks [here on the essence of algebraic structure](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/118922/242).

Comment: I also found [this related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3910015/what-exactly-is-mathbbz-n?rq=1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The benefit of the equivalence class point of view is its vast generality and its abstract simplicity (one person's "this gets buried in *other stuff*" is another person's "abstract simplicity").

Since you have an abstract-algebra tag, perhaps you have learned some group theory, including normal subgroups and quotient groups.

In your post, think of $G=\mathbb Z$ as a group under the operation of addition and $n\mathbb Z = \{nk \mid k \in \mathbb Z\}$ as a normal subgroup. The "equivalence classes" are defined by the relation $a \sim b$ if and only if $b-a \in n\mathbb Z$.

This definition generalizes to any group and normal subgroup.

That is, let $G$ be a group, with group operation denoted $g \cdot h$ and inverse operation denoted $g^{-1}$ (notice, I have switched to multiplicative notation, but this is just a notational change). Let $N < G$ be a normal subgroup. We can define an equivalence relation: $g \sim h$ if and only if $g^{-1} h \in N$. Letting $[g]$ be the equivalence class of $g \in G$, we can then define a group operation $[g] \cdot [h] = [g \cdot h]$. There's plenty of details to check: that the relation $g \sim h$ does, indeed, satisfy the axioms of equivalence relations (true whether or not the subgroup $N$ is normal); next that the operation $[g] \cdot [h] = [g \cdot h]$ is well-defined (this is where normality of $N$ is needed); and then one must work to verify the group axioms for this new operation.

The resulting group is called the "quotient of $G$ modulo $N$" and is sometimes denoted $G/N$. So the example of a quotient in your post is often denoted more formally as $\mathbb Z / n \mathbb Z$.

The outcome is that one obtains a very general and spectacularly powerful tool in group theory.

---

Let me also comment on your question of whether it is important to distinguish between the two definitions.

I would say "not really".

Given any equivalence relation $\sim$ on any set $X$, one common operation is to "choose representatives", i.e. choose one element in each equivalence class. This gives a subset of $X$ that is in one-to-one correspondence with the set of equivalence classes. In the case of a group and a normal subgroup, once a set of representatives has been chosen, one can then use [transport of structure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/646576/isomorphism-of-mathbbz-n-mathbbz-and-mathbbz-n/646600#646600) to put a unique group operation on the chosen set of representatives that makes the one-to-one correspondence into a group isomorphism. That's exactly what's going on in your question.

Sometimes there seems to be an "obvious" or a "natural" choice of representatives, and for your example the subset $\{0,1,2,...,n-1\}$ seems like the most obvious choice, although you will see that sometimes people choose $\{1,2,...,n-1,n\}$. For $\mathbb Z_3$ I think that $\{-1,0,+1\}$ is also a nice choice.

Comment: An [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/646600/242) *here* on transporting  quotient structure to normal form reps was already linked in the first comment on the question, so there's no need to give an offsite link.

Comment: Ah, very nice, thanks @BillDubuque. I changed the link.

Answer (score -3):

The definition
$$
\mathbb{Z}_n := \{0, 1, \ldots, n-1 \}
$$
does *not* declare it to be a subset of $\mathbb{Z}$. The symbols  "1", "2", ... ,"$n-1$" *look like* integers but they are not. That said, it's convenient to use the same symbols because their arithmetic is closely related to the arithmetic of the integers they happen to be the names of.

I suspect the "$ \subset \mathbb{Z}$" part of the question does not literally appear in Gallian. If it does, I think it should not.

As other answers point out, the definition using equivalence classes has far reaching generalizations.

Comment: I see a "${} \subset \Bbb{Z}$" in the Question following the subexpression you quote...

Comment: @EricTowers See the edit I was working on while you posted your comment.

Comment: To reiterate my earlier comment and explain the downvote: "*The symbols...look like integers but they are not...I suspect the '$\subset \Bbb Z$' ... does not literally appear... If it does, I think it should not*"  I, for one, have no qualms with allowing the objects in our set to be the literal integers themselves rather than equivalence classes.  The literal objects used is of as little importance to me as the font and color used to typeset them.  If we changed the font, they would still behave the same way mathematically.  All that matters to me is how they interact with one another.

Comment: @JMoravitz I think we have to agree to disagree. When you treat 2 as an element of $\mathbb{Z}$ you implicitly assume the arithmetic of its interaction with the other integers. When you use that name for an element of $\mathbb{Z}_7$ it has different arithmetic. It's not the "literal integer" 2. If I had to label it I'd call it a "figurative integer". Of course we agree that it's a good name for the equivalence class $[2]$ when it comes to calculation. There are reasonable pedagogic arguments for the position that it's "2 with a different kind of arithmetic".