# Show that there is a homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ under addition and $\mathbb{Z}$ under modular addition.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

I am taking a class in group theory (we began with basic number theory). I am trying to show that there is a homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_n$. By this, I mean from the integers to the integers mod n. I know this is a standard proof that has already been asked, but I do not understand them so I am trying to figure it out myself.

To show that a mapping $f$ is homomorphic, you need to show that $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$, but for this problem it's $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$. With the division algorithm I can write $(x+y)=qn+r$ where $0\le r< n$ to get $f(x+y)=r$. For $x$ and $y$,we get $x=q_1n+r_1$, $y=q_2n+r_2$, so $f(x)=r_1$ and $f(y)=r_2$. This is where I am stuck, I do not understand how to show that $r=r_1+r_2$. Intuitively, I think that I am missing a basic modular arithmetic lemma, but I don't know what it is. (The proofs that I saw do not explicitly say what said lemma is.)

Comment: Is it just $a+b\bmod n=(a\bmod n)+(b\bmod n)$?

Comment: We need more context, e.g. what is your definition of $\Bbb Z_n?$ Do you know basic properties of quotient rings and/or ring congruences, or do you only know elementary number theory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing $x = an + r_1$ and $y = bn + r_2$, we have, under addition modulo $n$, that:

$$x + y = an + bn + r_1 + r_2 = (a+b)n + (r_1 + r_2) \equiv r_1 + r_2 \text{ mod }n$$

Assuming that you are defining $f(x) := x \text{ mod }n$, the corresponding claim now follows from the fact that, in modular arithmetic, it is true that:

$$(r_1 + r_2) \text{ mod }n = (r_1 \text{ mod }n) + (r_2  \text{ mod }n)$$

In the equation above, the left hand side is $f(x + y)$ and the right hand side is $f(x) + f(y)$.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).
It's best for site health to delete this answer (which also minimizes community time wasted on dupe processing.) [once the question is clarified it will surely be a dupe, and your answer already is].

Comment: @BillDubuque I thought that by 1 )tagging this under solution verification and 2) providing exactly where I am confused with the proof I proved, it wouldn't be consider a dupe.

Comment: @Musical If the above is the sort of answer you seek then it is definitely a duplicate (of tens if not hundreds of prior posts). Adding an SV tag does not stop it from being a dupe - see the SV tag info.  See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3910465/242) in the first dupe for a more conceptual method.

Comment: @BillDubuque I did check the SV tag. The two posts that you recommended did not specifically help me when trying to figure out my proof. I have no idea what $((a\bmod n)+(b\bmod n))\bmod n)$ means. I hit a wall with my last step. I made a guess that I needed $a\bmod n+b\bmod n=(a+b)\bmod n$, which I did not know was true, and it just so happened that that was what I needed for this specific proof. Nowhere in my textbook does it mention that lemma so I did not know if it was true.

Comment: @Musical What *precisely* does $\,a\bmod n\,$ denote in your context?  Is it an integer, or a coset or congruence class, i.e. what is your definition of $\,\Bbb Z_n?\,$  As I commented on the question, you should specify this crucial context.

Comment: @Musical **Beware** that the 2nd displayed formula in the answer is incorrect if you interpret as pure modular arithmetic, e.g. $\,0 = (1+2)\bmod 3 \neq (1\bmod 3)+ (2\bmod 3) = 3.\,$ That's why we need an extra final mod on the RHS, then we correctly get $\,0 = 3\bmod 3 =0.\,$ Or instead we could interpret the RHS addition as an operation in $\,\Bbb Z_n\,$ (vs. $\Bbb Z),\,$ e.g. as coset addition. See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/614944/242) on $\!\bmod\!$ the operation vs. congruence relation.